# Im writing a library search program for my personal library, having trouble with a select with multiple words

Tags: php, sql

For example, if I search for 'cat' I get all the titles with the word 'cat' in it, such as 'cat in the hat'.

If I type in 'cat hat' I should get back 'cat in the hat', but the query returns empty, because its looking for exactly 'cat hat' and ignoring 'cat in the hat'.

I need some sort of select where it looks up all titles with any word I search for, then does that for the next word, etc... and then... I dont know, some sort of big AND thingy...

So far Im playing with somethign like:

```
$query = "SELECT title 
FROM books 
WHERE TITLE LIKE '%" . $search . "%' LIMIT 0,75;";
```

Probably need some sort of recursive function where it breaks the search input into an array of strings and does a search on each of those then merges them.

Ideas?

Comment: You should know that this opened to be attacked with sql injection

Comment: @lamak although you are correct I believe he is writing this program for his own use. So unless he intends to sql inject himself then it should be fine...

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT title 
FROM books 
WHERE TITLE LIKE '%" . $search1 . "%' AND LIKE '%" . $search2 . "%'  LIMIT 0,75;";
```

You need to add an AND clause for each search term. You could also add an OR if you wanted. They would give different results. OR would have a greater number of results and AND would of course be way more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with an array of inputs if it is simply querying against one field.  If it's multiple fields, you'll have to do it using a map.

One thing I would like to point out is that this looks suspiciously like a target for SQL injection.  Please be very wary when concatenating SQL queries together in a string.  The final result must be escaped and / or parameterized to prevent users from running arbitrary SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. Split the $search on normal symbols and white space and then build the query
2. Use [MySql Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Pitfalls:
Full SQL text search is the better option it will result in faster results.  Also be aware that your current query is vulnerable to SQL Injection please use [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to avoid this.

Thanks

Comment: its only faster if its a lot of records and its been indexed. otherwise a simple AND would work just as good.